# Using a function in a filter query in Solr

Tags: search, solr, filtering

I want to filter my result set before I search. I know the correct way to do this is by using the filter query (fq) parameter. However, I want to filter based on the output of a function performed on a field.

I have a field 'rating' which is an integer in the range of 1 to ~75000. The upper limit may change. I want to filter to the top 500 items with the highest 'rating'. In SQL this would be something like:

```
... ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 500
```

I think I can get the documents in solr ranked by rating descending by using the function rord(rating), so basically I would like to do:

```
fq=rord(rating):[0 TO 500]
```

But that does not seem possible. Does anyone know what else I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Yonik Seeley on the Solr mailing list:

> Solr 1.4 can now do range queries on
>   arbitrary functions:
>   http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html
>
> Note that ord() and rord() won't work
>   properly in Solr 1.4 trunk. Lucene has
>   changed to searching per-segment in a
>   MultiReader and hence you will
>   currently get the ord() or rord() in
>   that segment, not in the whole index.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you could not sort by the rating field and then simply take the first 500. That would be identical to your SQL example.

Comment: I can't limit the responses to 500 because a. That would take away the point of paging; and b. I want to run a filter query so I can facet inside the 500 documents.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-posted in the solr-user mailing list, answered by Yonik](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Using-a-function-in-a-filter-query-td496718.html).